# I don't understand how the ".year:" works in "datetime.datetime.today().year" line of code

Tags: python, django

So I am trying to learn Django and came across the following piece of code:

```
datetime.date.today().year
```

I understand it so far as - from the DateTime module, create an instance of the date class using the today method. But I don't understand how the `.year` portion of the code grabs the year.

Is it because the `today()` method of the date class returns a new object with a year?

Comment: The method returns an object with attributes including year, yes. A date. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today

Answer (score 2):

The [`today()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) returns the current local date as a [`date` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date). A `date` object has a `.year`, `.month` and `.day` attribute. We here thus use the [`.year` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.year) with:

> Instance attributes (read-only):
>
> `date.year`: Between `MINYEAR` and `MAXYEAR` inclusive.

Since `today()` thus returns a `date` object, we can retrieve the (read-only) attributes of that object and use `.year` to further process the function with the current year.

Comment: Ty Willem, appreciate the response. This clears it up for me. Ill accept the answer in 7 minutes :)